# Changing background color of inferior-ess-mode in Emacs

Tags: r, emacs, ess

As I'm working a lot with Latex and Sweave/knitr, I wondered if there's a possibility to change the background color of different modes in Emacs, e.g. change the background color of inferior-ess-mode (R) or ess-mode (R-Scripts) to black. At first, the following code seems to work. But as soon as I change from ess-mode to other buffers/modes, color settings are applied.

```
(defun pk-black ()
(set-background-color "black")
(set-foreground-color "white"))
(add-hook 'ess-mode-hook 'pk-black)
```

Is there a way to change the background color only for ess-mode/inferior-ess-mode in Emacs?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe useful: [BufferBackgroundColor](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BufferBackgroundColor)